# How to forward a curl external raw response to a SF Response object?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to make a route in a Symfony 3 app (server 1), which has to send a (filtered) request on a server 2, then send back the exact response given by the server 2 (same HTTP status code, headers and body).

With the native `curl` Php library, you can get the *raw* response (including headers), by setting the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option to `True`.

But the `Response` object from Symfony `HttpFoundation` seems to be only configurable by setting separately headers (inside the constructor, or with `$response->headers->set()`) and body (with `$response->setContent()`. I didn't find a way to set a *raw* response (with headers) into the `Response` object.

Is it possible, or how could it be done otherwise?

Here's my try:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/get", name="get")
     */
    public function getAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Filter/modify the query string, but keep it quite similar:
        $request->query->remove('some_private_attr');
        $my_query_string = http_build_query($request->query->all());

        // Setup the curl request:
        $curl = curl_init('http://localhost?'.$my_query_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // Include headers
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Return data as a string
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8200);

        // Perform the request, returning the raw response
        // (headers included) as a string:
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        // Get the response status code:
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($curl);

        // Here, how can I pass the raw external response ($result)
        // to a new Response object, without parsing the header
        // and body parts unnecessarily?

        // Of course, the following doesn't send the right headers:
        $response = new Response($result, $status_code);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use (for example):

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

which is described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#response

[The Response API](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) also describes each of the methods. I'm not certain what type of header you need to send.

Comment: I already know that, the problem is i'd like to set the whole response (headers+content) in one operation, since I get the response with headers already included (so there's no need to 'parse' it back and forth). But indeed I forgot to mention `$resp->headers->set()` (question edited)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I basically wanted to forward the `CurlResponse` as a `Response` by the controller.

I implemented this as follows, using the standard [Symfony HttpClient](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html):

```php
public function myAction()
    {
        /** @var Request $request */
        $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        $my_query_string = http_build_query($request->query->all());

        $client = HttpClient::create();
        $url = 'http://localhost?'.$my_query_string;
        $response = $client->request('GET', $url);

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $headers = $response->getHeaders();
        $content = $response->getContent();

        return new JsonResponse($content, $statusCode, $headers);
    }
```

If your content is already **Json**, add the optional parameter `true` to `JsonResponse`.